# Crash free user statistic inconsistent

Tags: google-fabric

The `latest release` module shows our crash free users at 99.6% but the crashlytics module shows 95.43% for our latest build. Both are on a 30 day timeline. The number of crashes between these modules have a huge discrepancy as well. Why are these numbers so different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investigation it turns out the `latest release` module only reports on the current day statistic even though it shows a time series graph at the top starting at the date the version was released. This is very confusing so thought I would leave this here for anyone else that is confused.

Comment: I would like much better crash free user statistics including number of users over time, etc. I'm not sure if it's there and I'm missing it, or what